# react prop not updating at correct time when passed from parent component state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am experiencing a really annoying bug in react and believe it is to do with calling methods that are not in one of my components `render` method. I think I have provided far too much code, and it will be difficult for anyone to provide help but let me try and explain my problem.

I am making an API call that returns 25 items. When the user clicks next it should change the background and play the song related to the background. This works, but when the user gets to the end of the list I want to go back to the first song. The background image goes back, but the wrong song plays. Then when the user clicks again the problem corrects itself.

I believe the issue is due to this line in the `nextSong` method.

`this.audio.src = this.state.songs[this.props.song + 1];`

Please see complete code below. If necessary I can provide a github link, where the project can be cloned which may be easier to debug.

I know SO isn't for fixing other peoples code, but just in case I am missing some fundamental react knowledge I wanted to ask here.

```
var App = React.createClass({

    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
              data: [],
              song: 0
        };
    },  

    nextSong: function() {
        if(this.state.song === this.state.data.length) {
            this.setState({song : 0});
        }else{
            this.setState({song : this.state.song += 1});
        }
    },
    previousSong: function() {
        if(this.state.song === 0) {
            this.setState({song : this.state.data.length});
        }else{
            this.setState({song : this.state.song -= 1});
        }
    },
    getData: function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '...',
            method: 'GET',
            success: function(response){
                this.setState({data: response.items});
            }.bind(this)
        })
    },
    render: function() {
        return(
            <div>
                <BackgroundImage src={this.state.data} image={this.state.song} />
                <Button src={this.state.data} song={this.state.song} nextSong={this.nextSong} previousSong={this.previousSong} />
            </div>
        )
    }
});
    var BackgroundImage = React.createClass({
        render: function() {
            var images = this.props.src.map(function(photo, i){
                return(photo.track.album.images[1].url)
            })
            var divStyle = {
                background: 'url(' + images[this.props.image] + ')'
            }
            return(<div style={divStyle}></div>)
        }
    });

var Button = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function(){
        return{
            songs:[],
            playing: false
        }
    },

    audio: new Audio,
    playSong: function(){
        this.setState({playing: true});
        this.audio.src = this.state.songs[this.props.song];
        this.audio.play();
    },
    pauseSong: function() {
        this.setState({playing: false});
        this.audio.pause();
    },
    nextSong: function() {
        this.audio.src = this.state.songs[this.props.song + 1];
        this.audio.play();
    },
    onClickNext: function(){
        this.setState({playing: true});
        this.props.nextSong();
        this.nextSong()
    },
    previousSong: function() {
        this.setState({playing: true});
        this.audio.src = this.state.songs[this.props.song - 1];
        this.audio.play();
    },
    onClickPrevious: function(){
        this.props.previousSong();
        this.previousSong()
    },
    render: function() {
        var self = this;
        var songs = this.props.src.map(function(song, i){
            self.state.songs.push(song.track.preview_url)
        });
        return (
            <div className="button">                
                <div className="next" onClick={this.onClickNext}>
                    NEXT
                </div>
                <div className="pause">
                    <p onClick={this.state.playing ? this.pauseSong : this.playSong}></p>
                </div>
                <div className="prev" onClick={this.onClickPrevious}>
                  PREVIOUS
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try using `componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState)` lifecycle method to get the props as they're available. Like so:

```
componentWillUpdate(nextProps, nextState) {
  if (nextProps.song !=== this.props.song) {
    this.audio.src = this.state.songs[nextProps.song];
    this.audio.play();
  }
}
```

Also, you wouldn't need to have the `this.audio.src=...` and `this.audio.play()` portion in the `previousSong()` and `nextSong()` methods.

I took a look to your code at Github and I found that changing those methods in `<App />` component to look like:

```
nextSong: function() {
    console.log(this.state.song)
    if(this.state.song === this.state.data.length - 1) {
        this.setState({song : 0});
    }else{
        this.setState({song : this.state.song + 1});
    }

},

previousSong: function() {
    if(this.state.song === 0) {
        this.setState({song : this.state.data.length - 1});
    }else{
        this.setState({song : this.state.song - 1});
    }

},
```

Note that you have to make the last index be equal to `data.length - 1` as `data.length` will be undefined.

Also, I've changed those methods in `<Button />` component as well:

```
onClickNext: function(){
    this.setState({playing: true});
    this.props.nextSong();

},

onClickPrevious: function(){
    this.props.previousSong();
},
```

And now, it seems to be working here for me.

Comment: As you would have the exact index of the song to play (because it'd go up to the parent component and back updated as prop), you could put inside of `componentWillUpdate: function (nextProps, nextState)` the `this.audio.src = this.state.songs[nextProps.song]; this.audio.play();` code and also take those out from other `nextSong()` and `previousSong()`.

Comment: cheers, any chance you could update your answer to show how this part of the button should look?

Comment: thanks man, still not working! argghhhhhh i appreciate your help. if you really wanna look the repo is here https://github.com/Pau1fitz/apis in the reactspotify folder. I have looked again and when I click previous to next or next to previous it always goes one too many (this prob makes no sense)

Comment: I took a look to your Github code and made it work (I guess). I've updated the answer to show what I've changed in order to make it work.

Comment: amazing! it works! need to figure out what you did now

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you should not do this:

```
this.setState({song : this.state.song += 1});
```

Because that will first set this.state.song and then setState, and this could make some conflict as you're updating state without alerting react. I'm not sure if react handles that correctly. Instead, simply do:

```
this.setState({song : this.state.song + 1});
```

(Same with `-=`)

**Back to the question:** you should keep track of the current song only in one place. In this case, you should keep it in the App component's state, and button component shouldn't.
So methods like nextSong have no place in your button component.
Instead, you update the song in your App component (like you're doing in its nextSong method) and pass the current song directly to your button component via props.

Then, you can detect whether the current song changes with lifecycle method `componentWillReceiveProps` like this:

```
componentWillReceiveProps: function(nextProps) {
    this.playSong(nextProps.song);
}
```

So, when you change state in App, it'll update and pass new props to Button, then Button will trigger componentWillReceiveProps with the new song and do its stuff.

Comment: thanks man, its kind of blown my mind now, maybe I have bee looking at it for too long. I thought I am just keeping track of the song in the `App` component. thats the only place the state is changed (i.e. the number of the song) `nextSong` is only used to update and play the next song as thats the component where the audio tracks are kept

Comment: i am passing the current song to the button as a `prop` --> see `song={this.state.song}`

Comment: The `nextSong` method of the Button component, for example, does this: `this.audio.src = this.state.songs[this.props.song + 1]`. If you update the song in the App component, you pass the updated (aka, the next song) via props to Button, so this.props.song is already updated, no need to sum +1 again. That's what I mean

Comment: yeah, sorry, I got that, but when I remove that it doesn't work either. That is why I am wondering why it isn't working with just `this.state.songs[this.props.song + 1]` as i expected it to be in tune with the background image, but it behaves somewhat differently. Would you mind updating the answer with how the Button component should look, incase i am implementing it incorrectly. If not, no probs, as i feel guilty asking for this much help

Comment: when i implement your answer I see `script.js:138 Uncaught (in promise) DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a new load request.` perhaps i am implementing it incorrectly

Answer (score 0):

The reason this happens is that you update the track index correctly in your `App` component, but not in your `Button` component. When you reach the **last song**, and call `this.props.nextSong()` from `Button`, `App` will set the index to 0. But after that, you also call `this.nextSong()` (from `Button`), which will play audio from the track at index `this.props.song + 1`.

This is probably where you've misunderstood things a bit. Here, `this.props.song` will still be the same as it was in `onClickNext()`, so it will actually try to play a song that doesn't exist (in your example it will try to play the song at index 25, but there's only songs at 0-24).

An **easy** solution would be to use the same logic in your `Button`, i.e. check when you've reached the end, and then play the song at index 0. But now you're keeping track of the same state twice, which really isn't a good idea.

A **better** solution would be to do as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39780971/1783792), or just let `App` play the audio.